# Pandas: get the min value between 2 dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, min

I have 2 columns and I want a 3rd column to be the minimum value between them.
My data looks like this:

```
   A  B
0  2  1
1  2  1
2  2  4
3  2  4
4  3  5
5  3  5
6  3  6
7  3  6
```

And I want to get a column C in the following way:

```
   A  B   C
0  2  1   1
1  2  1   1
2  2  4   2
3  2  4   2
4  3  5   3
5  3  5   3
6  3  6   3
7  3  6   3
```

Some helping code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                   'B': [1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]})
```

Thanks!

Comment: These would be min row values, not column values just for clarity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`df.min(axis=1)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html#pandas.DataFrame.min)

```
df['c'] = df.min(axis=1)
df
Out[41]: 
   A  B  c
0  2  1  1
1  2  1  1
2  2  4  2
3  2  4  2
4  3  5  3
5  3  5  3
6  3  6  3
7  3  6  3
```

This returns the min row-wise (when passing `axis=1`)

For non-heterogenous dtypes and large dfs you can use [`numpy.min`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html) which will be quicker:

```
In[42]:
df['c'] = np.min(df.values,axis=1)
df

Out[42]: 
   A  B  c
0  2  1  1
1  2  1  1
2  2  4  2
3  2  4  2
4  3  5  3
5  3  5  3
6  3  6  3
7  3  6  3
```

**timings**:

```
In[45]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                   'B': [1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]})
df = pd.concat([df]*1000, ignore_index=True)
df.shape

Out[45]: (8000, 2)
```

So for a 8K row df:

```
%timeit df.min(axis=1)
%timeit np.min(df.values,axis=1)
314 µs ± 3.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
34.4 µs ± 161 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

You can see that the numpy version is nearly 10x quicker (note I pass `df.values` so we pass a numpy array), this will become more of a factor when we get to even larger dfs

**Note**

for versions `0.24.0` or greater, use [`to_numpy()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html?highlight=to_numpy)

so the above becomes:

```
df['c'] = np.min(df.to_numpy(),axis=1)
```

**Timings**:

```
%timeit df.min(axis=1)
%timeit np.min(df.values,axis=1)
%timeit np.min(df.to_numpy(),axis=1)
314 µs ± 3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
35.2 µs ± 680 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
35.5 µs ± 262 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

There is a minor discrepancy between `.values` and `to_numpy()`, it depends on whether you know upfront that the dtype is not mixed, and that the likely dtype is a factor e.g. `float 16` vs `float 32` see that link for further explanation. Pandas is doing a little more checking when calling `to_numpy`

Comment: Perfect!. Thank you for the solution and the numpy.min suggestion. That is what I will implement as my df is large.

Comment: small note, with pandas 0.24.0 or higher, `df.to_numpy()` is preferred over `df.values`